# installing source control with Aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, tortoisesvn, aptana

I am using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.1.201207261642, I want to add my code any kind of source control for managability. Its just a pet project , which I am doing to learn ruby on rails.

When install SVN through aptana IDE , I am getting the following error.

Am I missing pre-requisites?

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend not using SVN if you're starting a new project. Git is pretty much the standard in the Rails community these days. If you're not keen on learning a new cli, Github released a GUI version for Windows. http://windows.github.com

Comment: Can you give instructions for connecting Git with Aptana ?

Comment: I'm sure if you google for it, you'll find something. I would encourage you to try the github tool though, there probably isn't anything Aptana provides that this tool does not.

Comment: @Beerlington You can't simply say _Hey use Git! It's better!_, and then tell someone to _Google it_ when asked a question. In this particular situation, there's no difference between using Git or Subversion. You're talking about one person using a single repository.

Comment: A) I didn't say Git was better and B) I've never once used Aptana so I can't give any instructions on how to use it. This is why I left a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get Subclipse working without prerequisites, uncheck:

- Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional)
- Subversion Revision Graph

They are not mandatory.

If you really want to use Subclipse Revision Graph, Add GEF to your update sites and install Draw2D: [Eclipse Update Site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/)

If you really want to use Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x, install Eclipse Marketplace. [This](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/quickstart) site would help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you want to use the *Subversion Revision Graph* and you're missing a dependency, and Aptana can't find it. There are two solutions:

- Uncheck *Subversion Revision Graph*. If you need it, you can use TortoiseSVN.
- [Install the missing dependency](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php). It's there on the bottom of your error message: org.eclipse.draw2d (version 3.2.0). It could be that it's just not installed, or that you have an older version installed. You might want to update all of your installed software and see if you can install it.

[Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276850/368630) mentioned that *Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional)* is also missing a prerequisite, but I don't see it. However, Mylyn is a issue tracking system for Eclipse and integrates to things like MantisBT, Rally and Jira. If you don't have an issue tracking system, you really don't need Mylyn. Go ahead and uncheck it.